# AWS Lambda JSONDecodeError

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I built a Crawler which should get me the Image and the Price of some Products from different Websites.
I have following Code running on my local PC (Python 3.7):

```
if SpecificWebsite in webpage_url:
   page = requests.get(webpage_url).text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
   image = soup.find('meta', property="og:image")
   url = image.get("content")
   script = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')
   jsonStr = script.text.strip()
   script = json.loads(jsonStr)
   Price = script['offers']['price']
   return(url, Price)
```

On my PC that works just fine.

Now i want to run that code with a AWS Lambda Function (Runtime: Python 3.7).
When executing the Lambda, i get following Error:

```
[ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 202, in lambda_handler
    script = json.loads(jsonStr)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

Log of the parsed text of interest:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "Product",
                        "productID": "XM080",
            "sku": "XM080",
            "image": "https://www.pepperworldhotshop.com/out/pictures/generated/product/1/340_245_75/kalenderfreigestellt.jpg",
            "description": "&lt;b&gt;Special Edition 2020 - Pepperworld Gewürz-Adventskalender&lt;/b&gt;: 24-tägige Rundreise durch die Gewürz-Welt: Enthält aromatische Gewürzmischungen, hochwertige Pfeffer und feinste Salze. Achtung! Nicht nur in der Vor-Weihnachtszeit ein tolles Geschenk!",
            "name": "PEPPERWORLD Gewürz-Adventskalender",
                            "gtin13": "4251390306302",
                                        "brand":"Pepperworld",
                        "offers": {
                "@type": "Offer",
                                            "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                                                        "price": "49.95",
                    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
                                "url": "https://www.pepperworldhotshop.com/de/geschenke/chili-geschenke/pepperworld-gewuerz-adventskalender/"
                }

                                                        }

        
        </script>
```

Log of jsonStr:

```
{
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "Product",
                        "productID": "XM080",
            "sku": "XM080",
            "image": "https://www.pepperworldhotshop.com/out/pictures/generated/product/1/340_245_75/kalenderfreigestellt.jpg",
            "description": "&lt;b&gt;Special Edition 2020 - Pepperworld Gewürz-Adventskalender&lt;/b&gt;: 24-tägige Rundreise durch die Gewürz-Welt: Enthält aromatische Gewürzmischungen, hochwertige Pfeffer und feinste Salze. Achtung! Nicht nur in der Vor-Weihnachtszeit ein tolles Geschenk!",
            "name": "PEPPERWORLD Gewürz-Adventskalender",
                            "gtin13": "4251390306302",
                                                                "brand":"Pepperworld",
                                    "offers": {
                "@type": "Offer",
                                            "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                                                        "price": "49.95",
                    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
                                                "url": "https://www.pepperworldhotshop.com/de/geschenke/chili-geschenke/pepperworld-gewuerz-adventskalender/"
                                }

                                                                                                        }
```

I´m kind of lost as it is the exact same code - are there any differences in how AWS Lambda functions process JSON - Operations?

Comment: Start by logging the actual page and text that you are trying to parse. It could very well be an HTML page telling you that AWS IPs are blacklisted due to scraping…

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! The site does not block the AWS IP. I included the log of the script i am trying to load into a JSON dict.

Comment: Log `jsonStr` as well before trying to parse it, to see exactly what your code is trying to do…?

Comment: When i Log jsonStr from AWS Lambda, it returns nothing. The Log of jsonStr from my PC is added in the question

Comment: So somewhere in there it goes wrong. Log your values at each step to figure out where exactly…

Comment: So it seems that 
jsonStr = scripts.text  
does not work with AWS Lambda. I figuered a way around that problem: using 
jsonStr = str(scripts.contents[0]) instead does the job.

Thanks for your help!